# Initial state of component is always using the previous updated state in the previous component

Tags: reactjs

To be more specific, when displaying a list of the same components containing `textarea`, how to set the initial state of the last component `textarea` to a specific value?

For example, I have a simple Note app.

It basically just adds, updates and deletes notes.

To make it simple I just use one `Note` component:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { MdDeleteForever } from "react-icons/md";

export const Note = ({ info, data, setData, isNewNote }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(info.text);
  console.log("text = ", text, "id = ", info.id);
  const onChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const value = event.currentTarget.value;
    setText(value);
  };

  const onSave = () => {
    const newNote = {
      id: uuid(),
      text: text
    };
    setData((prev) => [...prev, newNote]);
    // Need to reset the text for the unsaved new note
    setText("Try to add a new note.");
  };

  const onDelete = (event) => {
    const id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-value");
    setData((prev) => data.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`m-3 w-56 h-36 ${isNewNote ? "bg-teal-200" : "bg-yellow-300"}`}
    >
      <textarea
        className={`overflow-hidden p-2 bg-transparent focus:outline-0 resize-none border-transparent ${
          isNewNote ? "bg-transparent" : "bg-yellow-300"
        }`}
        name=""
        id=""
        cols="23"
        rows="3"
        value={text}
        onChange={onChange}
      ></textarea>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-end m-3">
        {isNewNote ? (
          <button
            className="w-20 h-7 drop-shadow-md bg-blue-500 text-slate-100 rounded-md hover:bg-blue-700 transition duration-300"
            onClick={onSave}
          >
            Save
          </button>
        ) : (
          <MdDeleteForever
            className="text-2xl drop-shadow-md hover:cursor-pointer hover:scale-125 transition duration-500"
            onClick={onDelete}
            data-value={info.id}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

App.js:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Note } from "./components";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      id: uuid(),
      text: "This is my first note."
    },
    {
      id: uuid(),
      text: "This is my second note."
    },
    {
      id: uuid(),
      text: "This is my third note."
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="mt-3 flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
      <div className="font-bold text-3xl">Note app</div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-wrap">
        {data &&
          data.map((note, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <Note info={note} data={data} setData={setData} />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        <div key="x1">
          <Note
            info={{ text: "Try to add a new note." }}
            data={data}
            setData={setData}
            isNewNote={true}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I pass some "placeholder" text as props to the Note component hoping the component will show the text when the note isn't saved to the list.

In the textarea, the text is decided by the `onChange` method but first-time display I sent the props to the `useState()` at the beginning of the component so the text would be what is stored in the `data` array or whatever "placeholder" text I put in the props.

Every time it displays the last `Note` component, it is reusing the text from the previous saved `Note` component, **UNLESS I specifically add a `setText()` at the end of the `onSave` function to reset the `text` state to the "placeholder" value**.

Why doesn't the last `Note` component update the `text` state with the incoming props? I have tried numerous ways to update the `text` with the "placeholder" text thinking that I could update the text when the last `Note` component is created but I always failed.

Am I missing the big picture here? How does a component keep its state when we render multiple components with the same code?

Example is here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/note-app-kpxolc?file=/src/components/Note.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a different `placeholder` prop to `Note` component as

[`CODESANDBOX DEMO`](https://codesandbox.io/s/note-app-forked-w1dbvw?file=/src/App.js)

**`App.js`**

```
<Note
    // YOU ARE NOT PASSING info HERE
    data={data}
    setData={setData}
    isNewNote={true}
    placeholder='Try to add a new note.'  // CHANGE
/>;
```

This `placeholder` will be used only in `Note` where user can `save` new note or the last one.

> Don't confuse `placeholder` with `value`. Both are different and has different purpose.

**`Note.js`**

You can set state from `info` object as:

```
const [text, setText] = useState(info?.text ?? '');  // If info.text is there then take this else take empty string
```

while `onSave` function you can reset its state to empty string so that `placeholder` will show up

```
const onSave = () => {
    const newNote = {
        id: uuid(),
        text: text,
    };
    setData((prev) => [...prev, newNote]);
    // Need to reset the text for the unsaved new note
    setText('');  // CHANGE
};
```

In JSX

```
<textarea
    className={`overflow-hidden p-2 bg-transparent focus:outline-0 resize-none border-transparent ${
        isNewNote ? 'bg-transparent' : 'bg-yellow-300'
    }`}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    name=''
    id=''
    cols='23'
    rows='3'
    value={text}
    onChange={onChange}
></textarea>;
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand this is a way to add a REAL placeholder. But we still need to reset the `text` state in `Note` component otherwise the last note will still display the previous updated `text`. I want to know the reason why the last note is using that updated value but not the one provided in `useState` when the last `Note` is rendered.

Comment: We are resetting the state to empty string as `setText('');  // CHANGE`

Comment: But why do we need to do this? when the component is re-rendered wouldn't it just grab the "placeholder" value in `useState`? Why is the `setText` reset line necessary? How does the state work in this situation?

Comment: In my solution I'm not using `placeholder` as `value` in `useState`. `const [text, setText] = useState(info?.text ?? '');`

Comment: Can you open the codesandbox link that I provided in the answer. You can see I separated the `placeholder` and `value` totally.

Comment: If you have added `placeholder` and `value` is not empty string then `placeholder` is shown in the `textarea` else `value`. You can read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#placeholder)

Comment: I know what you mean. It doesn't matter what you put there. We can just use `placeholder="some text"` in textarea as a fixed value.  But no matter what we put there, a `setText` reset in`onSave` is always needed.  It works just like my original code. I want to know the reason behind this. I want to know why the `value` attribute of the `textarea` doesn't get the given text when the component is re-rendered. Why does the last `Note` need to receive the `text` from `onSave`?

Comment: Because you are changing state when you enter text in `textarea`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247275/discussion-between-decpk-and-newguy).

Comment: Yes I have sent you messages in chat